# Excel COUNTIFS and converting custom date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have the following:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$6:B$36,">0",$A$6:$A$36,">=TODAY()")
```

Basically, column A is the date, every row from 1 to 31 for a month in a custom format. Column B onward is the shifts (in hours). I'm trying to work out how many shifts left in the month from today.

The date format is currently "Fri, 20/04/2018".

Easy solution would be change the date formatting to an actual date, not custom, but the spreadsheet gets uploaded to a software platform that only accepts the spreadsheet formatting as is (I don't have access to change that side of things)

Edit: got my columns mixed up. Formula "works" but doesn't return the correct count.

I’m assuming this is due to the custom date format. Is there a way to do the parse inside the COUNTIFS, trying to avoid a dummy columns

[image]

Comment: provide an example of your data... your shifts column can be in many ways...

Comment: If column H is the dates why you you are using `">0"` for `H` column condition?

Comment: It is still not clear what you want. If you just want to count how many days of work in a month rest, if it is one shift a day, why are you using `countifs` instead of  `countif`? I think something like `countif(B$6:B$36, ">=TODAY()"` should solve your problem...

Comment: @Dalton won’t that compare the hours to the date though. That’s why the COUNTIFS, we need to know what date that shift is - to clarify, the cells in column B onwards are just the total hours for the day, date is column A

Comment: A mistake, because you inverted the order before. Where you see B is A... another explanation for this mistake: you did not provide an example of your table, as asked before.

Comment: @Dalton when I’m back at a computer I’ll post an image. It’s literally column a is the dates for the month. Column b is the hours I.e 7.5, non-working days is blank

Comment: If you have "blank" for days, try with "<>" instead of ">0"...

Comment: Uploaded image for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image you put, here is a possible solution:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$6:$A$36;">="&TODAY();$B$6:$B$36;"<>''")
```

- `">="&TODAY()` - you compare the dates in the specified range (`$A$6:$A$36`) with the result of `TODAY()` formula;
- `"<>''"` - you test if the cells containing shifts (`$B$6:$B$36`) are not empty.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know you got success. =)

Answer (score 0):

The function below should produce the result you need.

```
Function CountShifts() As Integer
  Application.Volatile
  Dim arr As Variant, col As Integer
  col = Application.Caller.Column                              'Get the column that the function was called from
  arr = Range("A6:A36").Resize(31, col).Value2
  Dim row As Integer: row = UBound(arr)                        'Start at the bottom and work upwards
  Do While CDate(Split(arr(row, 1), ",")(1)) >= Now()          'until the date is before today
    CountShifts = CountShifts + IIf(arr(row, col) > 0, 1, 0)   'Increment CountShifts if there is a positive number
    row = row - 1
  Loop
End Function
```